# Name mapping - Excel

Tags: excel, if-statement, indexing

I have 2 worksheets.

1st worksheet contains the following:

[image]

Whilst the 2nd worksheet contains:

[image]

Column A in the 2nd worksheet contains the correct Account Names whilst columns B to E contains variants of the account names found in different reports.

What I want to do is to map the correct account names in Column A of the 2nd worksheet to column B in  the 1st worksheet.

I'm unsure how I will be able to do this - will it be by multiple IF statements in going through Columns B to E or something along the lines of index / match?

Thanks in advance

Comment: VLOOKUP is what you need

Comment: @PhilippSander will you have an example? I'm unsure how to implement VLOOKUP in this situation

Comment: read the documentation

Comment: @PhilippSander genuinely don't think VLOOKUP is the solution to the problem here. I want to match the Customer Name in Sheet1 with the name in the Report A-D in Sheet2 and output the Account Name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `index` function uses nested `match` functions to account for the multiple possible columns and locate the required **row**. However beware if your table has duplicate values *across records* (for example say cells B2 and D4 match) then this would not work accurately.

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!$A$1:$E$7,IFERROR(MATCH(Sheet1!B2,Sheet2!$B$1:$B$7,0),IFERROR(MATCH(Sheet1!B2,Sheet2!$C$1:$C$7,0),IFERROR(MATCH(Sheet1!B2,Sheet2!$D$1:$D$7,0),IFERROR(MATCH(Sheet1!B2,Sheet2!$E$1:$E$7,0),"not found")))),MATCH("Account Names",Sheet2!$A$1:$E$1,0))
```

Note that **if** the first nested `match` functions fail (name not present in table) then the internal result is "not found"... you won't see that because it becomes an argument for the `index` function, which obviously isn't recongised, and so you would just get a `#VALUE!` error. So it might be nice to wrap an `iferror` function around the whole thing.

Comment: Hi - thanks for your answer. I'm a bit confused how I can implement this. At the moment I have this: =INDEX(tbl_accountMapping,IFERROR(MATCH(B10,'Account Mapping'!C5:C137,0),IFERROR(MATCH(B10,'Account Mapping'!D5:D137,0),IFERROR(MATCH(B10,'Account Mapping'!E5:E137,0),IFERROR(MATCH(B10,'Account Mapping'!F5:F137,0),IFERROR(MATCH(B10,'Account Mapping'!G5:G137,"Mapped Name Not Found")))), MATCH("Account List Owners",'Account Mapping'!B4:H4,0) The bit I'm confused is the last Match... Why do you have "Account Names" and the reference is A-E?

Comment: The last Match formula uses "Account Names" because it's trying to find that column header in your accountMapping table (column A in your 2nd sample table above). The reference in my given formula is A-E because your accountMapping table sample shows the data in columns A-E. One further comment: In your current version of the formula, the column references use rows 5:137 --- but they actually need to include the header row, so should use 4:137... that's just an index/match/match thing: Imagine a simplified index function: `=index(A1:Z10, 5, 3)` ... this would return the value in cell C5.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to use `VLOOKUP`

Type this into Sheet1!A2

```
=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!B2,Sheet2!$B$2:$E$6,2,FALSE)
```

This will lookup the value Sheet1!B2 (Angela) in the table Sheet2!$B$2:$E$6, and will return the value from the matching row, column c (Angel).

I realise this isn't exactly what you asked for! But you need the account name column **AFTER** the column you are matching the value on.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think this will work. I can amend the layout of Sheet2 if need be. But basically I want to match the customer name in Sheet1 with the name in the Report A-D and output the Account Name. Is it possible?

Comment: `VLOOKUP` requires you to have the column you are looking up values in, as the leftmost column. You will need to reorder your columns, or do something more complicated, such as this ... https://www.excel-easy.com/examples/left-lookup.html

Comment: Would a nested IF work? =IF(Sheet3!B2=Sheet2!B2,Sheet3!A2,IF(Sheet3!C2=Sheet2!B2,Sheet3!A2,IF(Sheet3!D2=Sheet2!B2,Sheet2!A2,IF(Sheet3!E2=Sheet2!B2,Sheet3!A2,"Wrong"))))